# How to create new div immediately next to image like on Facebook's news feed on right side of page?

Tags: jquery, css

I am using jQuery 1.7.2

I have thumbnails stacked vertically on the left side of the page. As the user hovers their mouse over a thumbnail, I want a much larger version of that image to open in a div immediately to the right of the thumbnail.

What I want is almost exactly how Facebook does it with their news feed on the top right side of their page.

It's important to note that the div must FLOAT above everything else on the page.

I have tried creating the divs with a class and putting them immediately after the thumbnail, like this:

```
<img src="MyThumb-01.jpg">
<div class='HiddenDivUntilThumbnailIsHoveredOver'>
<img src="MyThumb-02.jpg">
<div class='HiddenDivUntilThumbnailIsHoveredOver'>
<img src="MyThumb-03.jpg">
<div class='HiddenDivUntilThumbnailIsHoveredOver'>
```

I have also tried using a div with an id and populating it with the photo. This is NOT what I want.

```
<img src="MyThumb-01.jpg">
<img src="MyThumb-02.jpg">
<img src="MyThumb-03.jpg">
<div id='TheBigPhotoGoesHere'>
```

So, what kind of div do I need with what kind of CSS to make a div immediately adjacent to to another div that is hovered over?

Comment: Have you looked at jQuery lightbox? http://leandrovieira.com/projects/jquery/lightbox/

Comment: I am not using plugins. Thanks!  (Yes, I have used lightbox with great results.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would wrap both images within a div with relative positioning, and add absolute positioning to the large image:

http://jsfiddle.net/7sZya/

Or with some fancy CSS transition: http://jsfiddle.net/7sZya/3/

```
<div class="img">
    <!-- image here -->
    <div class="largeimg"></div>
</div>


.img {
    background:grey;
    height:50px;
    position:relative;
    width:50px;
}
.largeimg {
    display:none;
    height:150px;
    width:150px;
    top:0px;
    left:50px;
    position:absolute;
}
.img:hover  {
    cursor:pointer;
}
.img:hover .largeimg {
    display:block;
    background:black;
}
```

Comment: This is EXACTLY what I wanted.  Thank you so much!  As soon as I upload it, I'll send you a link.

Answer (score 0):

The [jQuery UI Position plugin](http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Position) can be used to do what you want.

If you don't want the element to scroll with the page, attach it to the `body`and make its CSS position:

```
position: fixed;
```

Comment: I am not going to use a plugin. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You need to make an absolutely positioned div outside of everything (parent is body).  When you hover over the img, the div content is filled and its position is put adjacent to the img that is hovered.

Comment: I think I know what you mean. I'll give that a try right now.

Answer (score 0):

If you didnt want to use a library ive created a basic example here http://jsfiddle.net/Em2UJ/2/

```
    $('.hover').hide();
  $("img").hover(function(e)
   {
    var height = $(this).height();
    $('.hover').css("margin-top",-height);
    $('.hover').fadeIn();       
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Position absolutely.
2. Use some math with jquery to make it position properly.
3. Use css classes / ids to reference each element.

See http://jsfiddle.net/6ENHe/2/
html:

```
<img id="pop1" class="pop" src="http://26.media.tumblr.com/tumblr_lmw73jhwOB1qlyrujo1_500.jpg" />
 <!-- ^ big hidden img, below, thumb -->
<img data-pop="#pop1" class="thumb" src="http://26.media.tumblr.com/tumblr_lmw73jhwOB1qlyrujo1_500.jpg" height="100" width="100" />
```

js:

```
$(function(){

$('img.thumb').hover(function(){
    var self = $(this),
        popimg = $(self.data('pop')),
        offset = self.offset();
    popimg.css({'left': offset.left + $(this).width() + 'px', 'top': offset.top- (self.height() / 2)}); 
    popimg.fadeIn('fast');
}, function(){
    // Can add delay here if necessary
    $($(this).data('pop')).fadeOut('fast');
});
});
```

css:

```
.pop { position:absolute; display:none; }
```